# Model.matrix turning factors into dummies

Tags: r, function, matrix

I am trying to expand on this function:

```
vcov2sls <- function(s1, s2, data, type=2) {
  ## turn factor variables into dummies
  DATA <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(phantom ~ ., transform(data, phantom=0)))
  ## list variable names
  vn <- lapply(list(s1=s1, s2=s2), function(s)
    c(all.vars(s$call)[1], colnames(model.matrix(s))[-1]))
  ## auxilliary model matrix
  X <- cbind(`(Intercept)`=1, DATA[, c(vn$s1[1], vn$s2[-(1:2)]), F])
  ## get y
  y <- DATA[, vn$s2[1]] 
  ## betas second stage
  b <- s2$coefficients
  ## calculate corrected sums of squares
  sse <- sum((y - b %*% t(X))^2)
  rmse <- sqrt(mean(s2$residuals^2))  ## RMSE 2nd stage
  V0 <- vcov(s2)  ## biased vcov 2nd stage
  dof <- s2$df.residual  ## degrees of freedom 2nd stage
  ## calculate corrected RMSE
  rmse.c <- sqrt(sse/dof)
  ## calculate corrected vcov
  V <- (rmse.c/rmse)^2 * V0
  return(V)
}
```

The following part turns the factors into dummies:

```
DATA <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(phantom ~ ., transform(data, phantom=0)))
```

But I don't want to convert the factors beforehand. Instead I would prefer to do in the function, turning the first three lines into:

```
factornames <<- stringr::str_match_all(as.character(s1$terms)[3], 'as.factor\\(([A-Za-z]+)\\)')[[1]][,-1]
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data[factornames] <- lapply(data[factornames], factor)
```

But I do not understand to adapt the `DATA <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(phantom ~ ., transform(data, phantom=0)))` part. For example I do not understand what `phantom` does and how I should replace it.

I tried:

```
form_all <- all.vars(as.character(s1$terms)[3])
DATA <<- as.data.frame(model.matrix(form_all, data = data))
```

But it does not work properly.

This works (in DF_2 factors are converted beforehand):

```
s1.tobit <- AER::tobit(taxrate ~ votewon + industry + size + urbanisation + vote,
                  left=12, right=33, data=DF_2)
yhat <- fitted(s1.tobit)
s2.tobit <- lm(sales ~ yhat + industry + size + urbanisation + vote, data=DF_2)

lmtest::coeftest(s2.tobit, vcov.=vcov2sls(s1.tobit, s2.tobit, DF_2))
```

This is what I want to work (NOTE THE ADDED INTERACTION TERMS):

```
s1.tobit <- AER::tobit(taxrate ~ votewon + as.factor(industry):as.factor(size) + urbanisation + vote,
                  left=12, right=33, data=DF)
yhat <- fitted(s1.tobit)
s2.tobit <- lm(sales ~ yhat + industry + size + urbanisation + vote, data=DF)

lmtest::coeftest(s2.tobit, vcov.=vcov2sls(s1.tobit, s2.tobit, DF))
```

## DATA

```
DF <- structure(list(country = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "J", "J", "B", 
"B", "F", "F", "E", "E", "D", "D", "F", "F", "I", "I", "J", "J", 
"E", "E", "C", "C", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "C", "C", "H", 
"H", "J", "J", "G", "G", "J", "J", "I", "I", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
"A", "A", "G", "G", "E", "E", "J", "J", "G", "G", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "J", "J", "G", "G", "E", "E", "G", "G", "E", "E", "F", "F", 
"I", "I", "B", "B", "E", "E", "H", "H", "B", "B", "A", "A", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "F", "F", "E", "E", "I", "I", "J", "J", "D", "D", 
"F", "F"), year = c(2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 
2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 
2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 
2010, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005), sales = c(15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9), industry = c("D", 
"D", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", 
"E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "D", "D", "F", "F", "E", "E", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "F", 
"F", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "F", "F", "F", "F", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E", 
"E", "F", "F", "E", "E", "F", "F", "E", "E", "F", "F", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "F", "F"), urbanisation = c("B", 
"B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), size = c(1, 1, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 
5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5), base_rate = c(14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 29L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 24L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 29L, 29L, 14L, 14L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 33L, 33L, 19L, 19L, 24L, 
24L, 14L, 14L, 20L, 20L, 23L, 23L, 33L, 33L, 29L, 29L, 19L, 19L, 
33L, 33L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 33L, 33L, 29L, 29L, 33L, 
33L, 29L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 29L, 17L, 17L, 
30L, 30L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 29L, 29L, 24L, 
24L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), taxrate = c(12L, 14L, 14L, 
12L, 21L, 18L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 29L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
24L, 24L, 21L, 18L, 30L, 29L, 14L, 12L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 14L, 12L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 21L, 33L, 32L, 21L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 
12L, 14L, 20L, 20L, 22L, 25L, 32L, 33L, 30L, 29L, 18L, 21L, 32L, 
33L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 18L, 21L, 32L, 33L, 30L, 29L, 32L, 33L, 
29L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 18L, 19L, 30L, 
30L, 22L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 29L, 24L, 24L, 
21L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), vote = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), votewon = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))

DF_2 <- copy(DF)
## convert variables to factors beforehand
DF_2[c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10)] <- lapply(DF_2[c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10)], factor)
```

Comment: With `model.matrix()` we create a model matrix based on `data`. Because the response (i.e. the _Y_) isn't further needed and, thus, is arbitrary here we add a "phantom" using `transform()` and set it (also arbitrarily) to `0`.

Comment: May I ask what would be the advantages of not correctly coding the variables in question as factors? Finally, they are de facto categorical.

Comment: I think I am just poorly explaining what I want. I sometimes have variables which are coded as numerical, but which are actually factors. In addition, I am using your function within another function. Because of that last reason, I would like to have the function convert everything that either is a factor, and which I tell the function is a factor.

Comment: I am actually almost there. But for some reason, `DATA <<- as.data.frame(model.matrix(form_all, data = data)) ` produces `DATA` without the dependent variable.

Comment: I am going to delete this question, it is way to unclear. I manually added the dep variable now, I am not totally sure if that is smart because I assume that the matrix calculation just assumes that everything is the right order and does not use names.

Comment: I've noticed that `vcov2sls` doesn't work yet with interactions. I'm working on this and will inform you when I edit the [Cross Validated thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491330/2sls-or-iv-with-a-tobit-distribution-in-the-first-stage/491396#491396).

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much!